# Unable to get property 'hasClass' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reference, null, undefined

I am using AngularJS framework and I am using 'hasClass' inside jquery in order to have dropdown on mouse over. It is working fine in chrome and FF but in IE, it gives an error that "Unable to get Property hasClass of undefined or null reference" when I click on button and navigate to another page. 
This error does not show up every time but it appears often and in IE only. 
Similarly, sometimes instead of 'hasClass', it throws 'height' as undefined or null reference. 
Here is the code:

```
(function ($, window, delay) {

        var theTimer = 0;
        var theElement = null;
        var theLastPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        $('[data-toggle]')
          .closest('li')
          .on('mouseenter', function (inEvent) {
              if (theElement) theElement.removeClass('open');
              window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
              theElement = $(this);

              theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                  theElement.addClass('open');
              }, delay);
          })
          .on('mousemove', function (inEvent) {
              if (Math.abs(theLastPosition.x - inEvent.ScreenX) > 4 ||
                 Math.abs(theLastPosition.y - inEvent.ScreenY) > 4) {
                  theLastPosition.x = inEvent.ScreenX;
                  theLastPosition.y = inEvent.ScreenY;
                  return;
              }

              if (theElement.hasClass('open')) return;
              window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
              theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                  theElement.addClass('open');
              }, delay);
          })
          .on('mouseleave', function (inEvent) {
              window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
              theElement = $(this);
              theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                  theElement.removeClass('open');
              }, delay);
          });
    })(jQuery, window, 50); // 50 is the delay in milliseconds
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: How are we supposed to suggest anything without seeing any code at all ?

Comment: @Oriol: Thanks, Can you provide updated code?

Comment: should put this in angular directive

Comment: @Charlietfl: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problably, the problem is that `mousemove` event may fire earlier than `mouseenter` in some cases.

Then, better check if `theElement` is still `null` in `mousemove` event listener:

```js
.on('mousemove', function (inEvent) {
    /* ... */
    if (!theElement || theElement.hasClass('open')) { return; }
    window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
    theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        theElement.addClass('open');
    }, delay);
})
```

Comment: @Maddy Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it works :) About the other problem, it means that `grid.$topPanel` is undefined. I don't know angularjs nor its plugins, so I can't help more. Better ask that in another question.